# how to get single row form group

Tags: sql, oracle, plsql

[image]

I want a query which will give me desired output ,I am using following query

```
select table1.name1,table2.address 
from table1 join table2 
   on(table1.key=table2.key);
```

it is giving me result After join nut I only need single row for each key.
Any help will be appreciated.

Comment: Why [A, I] and not [A, J],why [B, K] and not [B, L or M]?

Comment: You'll need to explain what makes the combination of name A and address I desirable in the outcome while name A and address J is not desired.

Comment: any combination is allowed but only one row for each key

Comment: Your question should be how to return a single row in a group, which is different then distinct. Your desired output is exactly this - single, probably first row in a group. After join Group A has 2 rows, Group B - 3 etc... Try to formulate questions correctly.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

If any combination is allowed but only one row for each key then try this:

```
select table1.name1, MAX(table2.address) address
from table1
    join table2
       on table1.key=table2.key
group by table1.name1
```

Answer (score 2):

try like this

```
select *
from (select table2.address,
      rank() over ( partition by table1.name1 order by table1.key) rn
      from table1 join table2 on(table1.key=table2.key))
where rn = 1
```